# Virtual methods with deduced return type in G++

Tags: c++, g++, virtual-functions, auto, vtable

There is a nice question explaining why virtual functions cannot use return type deduction: [Why can't virtual functions use return type deduction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268721/why-cant-virtual-functions-use-return-type-deduction)

Surprisingly it appears that GCC allows such possibility (as a language extension). For example, this program is accepted by GCC:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual auto f() -> auto { return 1; }
};

struct B: A {
    virtual auto f() -> auto override { return 2.5; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A & a = b;
    std::cout << b.A::f() << ' ' << b.f() << ' ' << a.f();
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n3ejPshe7

I guess that GCC is wrong here at least with pedantic flags `-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` where all extensions must be turned off.

But the question is about the program output, which is `1 2.5 0`. Since expressions `a.f()` and `b.f()` are evaluated to distinct values then struct `B` actually has two different virtual functions despite of `override` keyword, which looks as a bug.

Comment: fyi link to the latest draft - https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#general-14