# function declared to return one type, actually returns another type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-bug

I am almost sure that the following is a bug of Visual Studio compiler, but it is so hard to believe that I decided to double check here:

```
struct A {
    constexpr virtual int f() { return 0; }
};

struct B : A {
    constexpr auto f() { return 1.1; }
};

constexpr int g() {
    B b;
    A & a = b;
    return a.f();
}

static_assert( g() != 1 );
static_assert( g() == 1.1 );
```

`g()` function declared to return `int` type, passes compile-time check `g() == 1.1` meaning that `g()` actually returns a `double`-value. This behavior is reproducible in most recent MSVC compiler, online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6sGET7773

Is it right that the program is malformed because of `B::f()` declaration, which cannot contain `auto` as return type?

Comment: looks like msvc bug.

Comment: g++ gives "error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual constexpr auto B::f()’".

Comment: if you add `override` theres a warning https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/165TMqhrf. I am almost certain that it should be an error as it is in gcc

Comment: [clang errors](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vhv6oTq84).

Comment: Is `static_assert` required to give an error if the expression can't be evaluated at compile time?

Comment: @MarkRansom its all `constexpr` here

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, it will give an error like "non-constant condition for static assertion".

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268721/why-cant-virtual-functions-use-return-type-deduction

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `constexpr` allows but doesn't guarantee an expression to be compile time. There are other conditions that must be met too.

Comment: @MarkRansom its not "allowed" but "required". If the function is declared as `constexpr` then it must be possible to be called at compile time, and the `static_assert` does that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number surely you know it's more complicated than that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081905/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom yes its more complicated, sometimes I forget that ;)